# Centos7 g++ "to_string is not in a member of std"

Tags: c++, gcc, g++

I have some pretty standard C++ code, in which I am using `to_string` to add a sting and an int together, like this:

```
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Color{
public:
    int red, blue, green;

    Color(int r, int g, int b){
        red = r;
        green = g;
        blue = b;
    }

    string to_string(){
        string color = "(" + std::to_string(red) + ", " + std::to_string(green) + ", " + std::to_string(blue) + ")";
        return color;
    }

    string colorize(string text){
        string styled = "\033[38;2"+std::to_string(red)+";"+std::to_string(green)+";"+std::to_string(blue)+";177m"+"\n"+text+"\n"+"\033[0m";
        return styled;
    }

};
```

When I try to compile this using g++ on Centos7, I get the error "to_string is not in a member of std". What do I need to do? Why is this not working?  I'm running the build command `g++ main.cpp`

I’m running gcc version 4.8.5

Comment: Which version of GCC are you using?

Comment: @NutCracker whatever the latest version is,I just reinstalled it and ran a full update

Comment: @Laif Did you include the header <string>?

Comment: do `g++ -v` and let us know

Comment: Show us an entire program, the exact command line used to compile it, and the result of `g++ --version`. We might help.

Comment: @Laif Have you included the `-std=c++11` flag?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Yes, the program compiled correctly using my local version of CMake, this only happens when I move it to my Linux box.

Comment: @NutCracker yes, it doesn’t recognize that as a flag, likely due to versioning. I can’t check right now but will update with the version later

Comment: sounds like you have a very old version of gcc then

Comment: @M.M would running an yum update on it not update it to the latest version? My kernel was fully updated yesterday

Comment: In order to answer this question, we need a [mcve] (showing which headers you are including, whether you have a `using namespace std;`, etc.), *and* we need to know which compiler flags you are passing. Please [edit] your question.

Comment: @Laif it would be simpler to look at the output of `g++ -v` than trying to reason about what version you might have

Comment: @CodyGray I didn’t include one as an originally posted this on Super User. Literally that line in a main method will break

Comment: Also the code in the question would not produce that error message , since there is no use of `std::` in the code

Comment: I don't know why you would have thought this would be on-topic for Super User. That line causing the breakage is C++ code, which isn't something that they deal with on Super User. Either way, since this is Stack Overflow, we need more information.

Comment: @CodyGray well, if using the OS's update tools produced a broken compiler installation, it would be a topic for Super User?   Of course we are far from establishing that based on the crumbs posted so far.

Comment: That's not even close to the issue that is being described here, @M.M. The problem described is that they have some C++ code that they believe is valid, yet it is not compiling. That's pretty much the epitome of a programming question. Furthermore, even if the issue is a messed up toolchain, that would still be on-topic here, not Super User.

Comment: I added the relevant code, any line that contains `std::to_string` is flagged by the compiler, I figured it would be on topic for super-user as in every other environment I tested it worked, it only threw this error on a specific g++ compiler on a linux system. Where does this belong if its off topic here? Can you re-open it now that I've given code?

Comment: @Laif you still haven't posted your build command and the output of `g++ -v`

Comment: @M.M Because it was so vanilla, I included it anyways, and have answered the question.

Comment: @CodyGray When you get a chance please remove the flag on this or tell me what I’m missing, I would’ve loved to have found this question earlier today and don’t want others to not find it either

Comment: @Laif the question still doesn't contain the version output  (note that this was requested in the very first comment posted, and answering it at the time would have saved you 51 minutes ...)

Comment: @M.M Note that I literally said I couldn’t check it as I wasn’t at my computer. What exactly did you want me to do from my local target to find the version?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe what you are missing is a compiler flag `-std=c++11` since `std::to_string` is introduced in C++11 version of the standard.

In the older versions of GCC you can use `-std=c++0x` for C++11 or `-std=c++1y` for C++14.

Comment: Second line worked, I have no clue why I would be running an older version though, I must fundamentally not understand what `yum update` does. I am running v4.8.5. Why is it not updating?

Comment: @Laif I believe that's because the default GCC version in CentOS 7 repository is 4.8.5. That's why it's not updating. I suggest you update GCC by building it from source.

Comment: `yum update` installs newer packages from the CentOS repositories. If gcc 4.8.5 is the newest version in the repository (which it is), then that's what you get. If you don't want packages that are several years old, use something newer than CentOS 7. For example, CentOS 8 is now available. If you have to stay on CentOS 7, consider installing the `devtoolset-8-gcc-c++` package which makes a newer GCC available.